# Spark not able to access hbase but able to access with java code

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am using  spark 1.3.0 with hbase 1.0. After one week. Hbase run successful with java code. But when using Hbase with spark giving error. I also check with hbase shell is work fine. This errors occurred after long time otherwise work fine with spark also.

I already check hadoop and hbase cluster health is fine.

at spark UI

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Enable/Disable failed 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.isTableOnlineState(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:110) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isTableDisabled(ConnectionManager.java:907) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.relocateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1076) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.relocateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1064) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionLocation(ConnectionManager.java:885) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:78) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124) 
    ... 23 more 
 Caused by:org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/table/my_sample_table 
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99) 
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) 
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:360) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getData(ZKUtil.java:685) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTableStateClientSideReader.getTableState(ZKTableStateClientSideReader.java:186) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTableStateClientSideReader.isDisabledTable(ZKTableStateClientSideReader.java:60) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.isTableOnlineState(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:108) 
    ... 29 more
```

In some cases

```
   WARN  ZKUtil:484 - hconnection-0x792dd4040x0, quorum=Megatron:2222, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getCat org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
 clusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:833)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:623)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor530.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.initialize(TableInputFormat.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1511)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1006)
    at  org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.count(JavaRDD.scala:32)
```

But error occurred first when try to put something into hbase.
Second error when try to read from hbase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the HBaese Table locking. The is in hung up or limbo state.
There are some suggested solutions.

Run following commands:

- hbase hbck -fix
- HMaster reboot

If above solution fails

- Restart the Master

If above solution fails

- Restart The Zookeeper

If everything fails

- Restart the cluster

More details can be found at this url:
[JIRA Ticket](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html)

Comment: I restart my application then work fine. I think some connection issue.